# jQuery animation content slider loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am having some trouble with a content slider I am building. There are 4 boxes of content placed inside of  tags positioned absolutely inside of a relatively positioned wrapper. From left to right the boxes have an ID #module1, #module2, #module3, and #module4 respectively. When I click a button I want the content to scroll right.

1. #module4 should animate off the right side of the page, hide, then animate back into view on the left side of the page.
2. #module3 should go into place where #module4 was and have opacity set to 50% same as #module4.
3. #module2 should move into the place where #module3 was.
4. #module1 should have opacity set to 100% and move to where #module2 was.

The issue I am having is when #module4 scrolls to the right off of the page, it then is visible when it moves over to the left side of the page. I cannot seem to figure out how to properly hide this  from view until it scrolls into view on the left side.

Here is my animation code:

```css
#module1,#module2,#module3,#module4{position:absolute;top:0;width:31.9444%;height:200px;background:#999;}
.wrapper{width:100%;height:220px;position:relative;}
button{position:relative;z-index:1000;}
```

```html
<body onLoad="contSlidr()">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="module1">Module1</div>
  <div id="module2">Module2</div>
  <div id="module3">Module3</div>
  <div id="module4">Module4</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
      //////////////////////////////////
      //       V a r i a b l e s      //          
      //////////////////////////////////
      var t = 400;
      var mod = [$('#module1'),$('#module2'),$('#module3'),$('#module4')];
      var m2 = mod[1].width();
      var scrnW = $(document).width();
      //////////////////////////////////
      function contSlidr(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
          mod[0].css('left','-23%');
          mod[0].css('opacity','.5');
          mod[1].css('left',scrnW*0.14583);
          var m2PosL = scrnW*0.14583;
          mod[2].css('left',m2 + m2PosL + (scrnW*.041667));
          mod[3].css('left','88.75%');
          mod[3].css('opacity','.5');
        });
      }
      //////////////////////////////////
      function animateRight(){
        var m2PosL = scrnW*0.14583;
        mod[0].animate({
          left:scrnW*0.14583,
          opacity: 1
        },t);
        mod[1].animate({
          left: parseInt(m2 + m2PosL + (scrnW*.041667))
        },t);
        mod[2].animate({
          left:"88.75%",
          opacity:.5
        },t);
        mod[3].animate({
          left:"120%",
        },{duration:t/2});
        mod[3].css('left','-120%');
        mod[3].animate({
          left: "-23%",
        },{duartion:t});
        var b = mod.pop();
        mod.unshift(b);
      }
      //////////////////////////////////
    </script>

<button onMouseUp="contSlidr()">Set Left</button>
<button onMouseUp="animateRight()">Move Right</button>
</body>
```

Comment: use `onmouseover` instead of onMouseUp there is no default onMouseUp event in DOM EVENTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas `.animate()` makes an entry in the fx animation queue, `.css` does not - its action is immediate.

Therefore the sequence `mod[3].animate(...); mod[3].css(...); mod[3].animate(...)` will not behave as you wish.

You want for the first of those animations to complete before applying the `.css()` and initiating the second animation :

```
mod[3].animate({left:"120%"}, t/2).promise(function() {
    mod[3].css('left','-120%').animate({left: "-23%"}, t);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it seems as if in my current code that the css just gets ignored so I think you are onto something with your explanation. When I try the code you provided the mod[3] just disappears. I think you have brought me a little closer to solving this problem.

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried to verify the css/animations, just to provide a pattern that will sequence them. You may just need to play around with those percentage values.

Comment: Another (better?) approach would be to deep-clone mod[4], adjust the clone's 'left' to position it to the left of mod[0] and append to the wrapper .... then animate all four divs to slide right. Finally tidy up, removing the now defunct original div that was cloned and keeping `mod` up to date.

Answer (score 1):

This code fixed it for me. 
Thank you both for your help!

```
  function animateRight(){
    var m2PosL = scrnW*0.14583;
    if(c > 5){
     c = 1 
    }
    mod[4] = mod[3].clone().attr('id','mod'+c);
    mod[4].appendTo('.opinionCon');
    mod[4].css('left','-120%');
    mod[0].animate({
      left:scrnW*0.14583,
      opacity: 1
    },t);
    mod[1].animate({
      left: parseInt(m2 + m2PosL + (scrnW*.041667))
    },t);
    mod[2].animate({
      left:"88.75%",
      opacity:.5
    },t);
    mod[3].animate({
      left:"120%",
    },{duration:t/2}).promise().done(function(){
      mod[4].remove();
    });
    mod[4].animate({
      left: "-23%",
    },{duartion:t});
    var b = mod.pop(); 
    mod.unshift(b); 
    ++c;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function animateRight(){
    var m2PosL = scrnW*0.14583;
    mod[0].animate({
        left:scrnW*0.14583,
        opacity: 1
    },t);
    mod[1].animate({
        left: parseInt(m2 + m2PosL + (scrnW*.041667))
    },t);
    mod[2].animate({
        left:"88.75%",
        opacity:.5
    },t);
    mod[3].animate({
        left:"120%",
    },{duration:t/2});
    mod[3].css('left','-120%');
    mod[3].css('opacity', '0');
    mod[3].animate({
        left: "-23%"
    },{
        duartion:t, 
        complete: function () {
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
        }
    });

    var b = mod.pop();
    mod.unshift(b);
  }
```

Comment: This is close but, the div's are not animated when sliding they just disappear then reappear.

Comment: Oops! I guess I didn't understand the original question. Glad it worked out